# Jackson Date deserialization with specific locale

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Is it possible to define the locale of a Date for the default deserializer during the deserialization phase on a per property basis?

I'm thinking of something like the JsonFormat annotation but for deserialization:

```
@JsonProperty("date")
@JsonFormat(locale = "en")
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

So independently of the machine's default locale, the parser will always be able to deserialize the date given in a specific locale, like: "Sun, 15 Apr 2012 17:00:00 GMT"

Comment: Do you want to set `locale = "en"` for all `Date` properties? Or you want to set for some properties `locale = "en"` and for other `locale = "us"` (for example). Did you see setDateFormat method in ObjectMapper - http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html?

Comment: As I said on the question, I want to set the locale "on a per property basis", i.e. the locale would only be applied to the deserialization of the property the annotation refers to (in this case, it would only be applied to the deserialization of "date"). Other Date properties would not be affected. I have implemented a workaround by using String instead of Date and doing the deserialization manually inside the setter and forcing a specific locale, but a more elegant solution would be better.